# C# Polymorphic constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, polymorphism

I have a base class `Item` and a child class `Ball` that inherits from `Item`.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint ID { get; set; }

    public Item(ItemData data)
    {
        Name = data.Name;
        ID = data.ID;
    }
}

public class Ball : Item
{
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public Ball(BallData data) : base(data)
    {
        CatchRate = data.Radius;
    }
}
```

They're constructor takes in an `ItemData` or a `BallData` object. Just like `Ball` and `Item`, `BallData` inherits from `ItemData`:

```
public class ItemData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint ID { get; set; }
}

public class BallData : ItemData
{
    public float Radius { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have an `ItemData` object `itemDataObj`. Note that I don't know whether this is also a `BallData` object (deserialized from and XML file). What I want to do is have the following code create a `Ball` object if `itemDataObj` is also a `BallData` object and create an `Item` if `itemDataObj` is just an `ItemData` object:

```
new Item(itemDataObj)
```

Basically, I want my constructors to form a chain of responsibily (polymorphic), where the appropriate one is chosen for the respective type of `ItemData`.

Comment: Constructors are *not* polymorphic. The "deserialization" code (eg. provided by a specific serialization library/framework or factory-reader method) is responsible for calling the *correct* constructor.

Comment: @user2864740 Ah, thanks. That's too bad.

Comment: A polymorphic constructor makes no sense.  It's the one time you have to know the concrete type of the object.  In this case, you create a `new Ball`.  The ball constructor can make all the necessary decisions, including whether to call the base class constructor as well as creating a BallItem

Comment: Factory pattern instead

Comment: Yes, check out the Factory Pattern, and possibly Dependency Injection, one of which should solve your higher-level problem.

Comment: I tried to avoid using the factory pattern as it seems counter-intuitive to use a bunch of if-clauses in a polymorphic system, but I guess I can't really avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to find a solution for this specific case by implementing a `GetItem()` method:

```
public class ItemData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Item GetItem()
    {
        return new Item(this);
    }
}

public class BallData : ItemData
{
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public override Item GetItem()
    {
        return new Ball(this);
    }
}
```

This way I can do:

```
itemDataObj.GetItem();
```

to get my `Item` or `Ball` respectively.

Comment: Using **dynamic binding**  is great for such use cases. A similar technique is used for the [visitor-visited](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) design pattern.